# Перенос данных между таблицами в SQL

Tags: sql

Как перенести данные из нескольких столбцов одной таблицы в один столбец другой таблицы sql?

Comment: @вот так, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При таком вопросе могу посоветовать использовать конкатенацию и приведение типов.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar ) SELECT  table2.column1, table2.column2, 8, 'some string etc.' FROM    table2 WHERE   table2.ID = 7
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
insert into `table1` (field)
select field1 from `table2`
union 
select field2 from `table2`
...
```

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас попробую переделать

Comment: @вот так не тратьте очки уважения на награждение. Достаточно нажать на палец вверх. Если ответ правильный, то нажать галку рядом с ним.